# Adding image to the background of UI

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I wanted to add image to the background of the window but failed to do that...
I tried `tk.Canvas` after some googling but didn't work..I was expecting all the widgets on that image

```py
import rotors;import tkinter as tk;from tkinter import HORIZONTAL;import tkinter.messagebox as mbx;import pyperclip
class UI():    
    def __init__(self, window, encryption):
        self.encryption = encryption
        self.window = window
        self.window.title('Security Window')
        self.window.minsize(width = 500, height = 200)
        self.x = tk.StringVar()
```

I tried a lot to add the background image to the UI but failed `Canvas` and `Label` were few options that I had tried.
[image]

Any background image is fine for me but need to know how can I do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your **init** method, in your UI class, to add **self.bg** and **self.back_ground**:

```py
[...]
class UI(): 
    def __init__(self, window, encryption):
        self.encryption = encryption
        self.window = window
        self.window.title('Security Window')
        self.window.minsize(width = 500, height = 200)
        self.bg = tk.PhotoImage(file = "green.png")
        self.back_ground = tk.Label(image=self.bg)
        self.back_ground.place(x = 0,y = 0)
        self.x = tk.StringVar() 
[...]
```

(Image can be downloaded here : https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Solid_green.png)

EDIT:
If you wanna resize the image to fill all the background, you can use the PILLOW lib:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("green.png")
img = img.resize((500, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

So it would give something like this:

```py
[...]
class UI():    
    def __init__(self, window, encryption):
        self.encryption = encryption
        self.window = window
        self.window.title('Security Window')
        self.window.minsize(width = 500, height = 200)
        img = Image.open("green.png")
        img = img.resize((1000, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img.save('green_resized.png')
        self.bg = tk.PhotoImage(file = "green_resized.png")
        self.back_ground = tk.Label(image=self.bg)
        self.back_ground.place(x = 0,y = 0)
        self.x = tk.StringVar()
[...]
```

Comment: I think you can also help me put those widgets on right place 
I mean I wished `Entrybox` on the top those six `scales` adjacent to each other but below that `entry` finally those two `button` on the bottom `left & right`
can you do that??

Comment: Can you please tell me how `.place` works why not `.grid()`

Comment: `.place` allows you to put your item wherever you want on your window (using pixels, so it is harder to be more precise than this), and `.grid` does some window spliting depending on how many rows and columns you want to use, you then decide in which square of your screen you want to place an item.

Comment: It is not too difficult to change the position of each elements in your grids using the correct columns and rows. But it might be better to create another issue, as this is no longer a background problem.

Comment: Exactly!!
The issue is they look misplaced even if we have proper rows&columns....

Comment: I did this : https://pastebin.com/xJBgh32p
Using columnspan, and modifying a little the disposition, you can try and play with the parameters, as it might give you some ideas on how to place your items.